# Table bug in answer?

Tags: discussion, bug

I posted an answer, and the table didn't show up!

Is this a bug?

[Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/314194/saying-parts-of-speech/314195#314195) is the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a blank line both before and after the table. But the fact that it looks like it's going to work is a bug, already reported here: [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359192/323179)